# Get variable data from one form to another in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, hyperlink

I wrote a program to calculate payroll data once an employee enters their information and hours. I am having a problem reading the data from variables in one form to another. What I was trying to do was reading from a form called TimeSheet in my other form called Payroll_Submission. Here is the code I have so far and I really need to get that data from the other form to do my calculations. Please let me know if you need my TimeSheet code, it is long so I didn't attach it this time.

```
Public Class Payroll_Submission

Private Sub Payroll_Submission_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0

    lblEmployee.Text = TimeSheet.EmpName
    lblSuperName.Text = TimeSheet.Supervisor
    lblReport.Text = TimeSheet.Period

    If Not TimeSheet.flag Then
        lblHoursWorked.Text = TimeSheet.txtMon1 + TimeSheet.txtTues1 + TimeSheet.txtWed1 + TimeSheet.txtThurs1 + TimeSheet.txtFri1 + TimeSheet.txtSat1 + TimeSheet.txtSun1
        If lblOvertimeHours.Text > 40 Then
            lblRegHours.Text = 40
            lblRegHours.Text = lblHoursWorked.Text - 40
        Else
            lblRegHours.Text = lblHoursWorked.Text
            lblOvertimeHours.Text = 0
        End If
        lblOvertimeHours.Text = "$15"
        lblRateOver.Text = "$22.50"

        HourlyPay.Text = Convert.ToInt32(lblRegHours.Text) * 15
        lblOvertimeHours.Text = Convert.ToInt32(lblOvertimeHours.Text) * 22.5
        lblGrossPay.Text = Convert.ToInt32(HourlyPay.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(lblOvertimeHours.Text)

        If TimeSheet.chk1.Checked Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

        If TimeSheet.chk2.Checked Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

        If TimeSheet.chk3.Checked Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

        If TimeSheet.chk4.Checked Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

        If TimeSheet.chk5.Checked Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

        If TimeSheet.chk6.Checked Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

        If TimeSheet.chk7.Checked Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

        lblPTOHours.Text = counter

    End If

    HourlyPay.Text = Convert.ToInt32(lblRegHours.Text) * 15
    lblOvertimeHours.Text = Convert.ToInt32(lblOvertimeHours.Text) * 22.5
    lblGrossPay.Text = Convert.ToInt32(lblRegHours.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(lblOvertimeHours.Text)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what your wanting to do correctly, it is infact very simple.
In your Timesheet form do you call your Payroll Form like this?

```
dim payroll as new Payroll_Submission
payroll.showdialog()
```

If you do it like this, you should be able to access all the controls on the payroll from by doing:

```
payroll.lblEmployee.Text = Me.EmpName
```

etc etc.

This will then set each of the labels and other controls on the Payroll form to the Variables that you have in your Timesheets form. 
You need to make sure that you set your controls on the Payroll form before you do .showdialog.

It should all look like this:

```
    dim payroll as new Payroll_Submission
    payroll.lblEmployee.Text = Me.EmpName
    payroll.lblSuperName.Text = Me.Supervisor
    payroll.showdialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you create the `Payroll_Submission` form from your `Timesheet` form I would look at adding a second constructor to your `Payroll_Submission` form:

```
Private _ts As Form

Public Sub New(ts As Form)
    Me.New()
    _ts = ts
End Sub
```

When you create the form pass a reference to your form through the constructor

```
    Dim ps As New Payroll_Submission(Me)
```

Then, once you change references to `TimeSheet` to be `_ts`, your code should work fine.

Just looking at your code, you could also do this to shrink it down a bit for the calculation of `counter`:

```
Dim cbs As New List(Of CheckBox) From _
{ _
    _ts.chk1, _ts.chk2, _ts.chk3, _
    _ts.chk4, _ts.chk5, _ts.chk6, _
    _ts.chk7 _
}
Dim counter = cbs.Where(Function (cb) cb.Checked).Count()
```

Comment: I added the code above and it makes every other instance of TimeSheet an error and Me.New is also an error. Wants me to generate method stub for 'New' in the project.

Comment: Should be `InitializeComponent()` instead of `Me.New`

Comment: @compucrazy - Just change `TimeSheet` to `_ts` in your code and it should be fine.

Comment: Also `InitializeComponent()` will work, but I was trying to get constructor chaining to work. It's been a while since I've written in VB.NET so I may have got the syntax wrong. It's better to use constructor chaining.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Should that code be in the TimeSheet form? I tried to put that in there and it just gave me a bunch of errors.

Comment: @compucrazy - No, it should be in the `Payroll_Submission` form.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables in the Timesheet form as Friend. e.g.

```
Public Class Timesheet
  Friend EmpName As String
  Friend Supervisor As String
```

Comment: I declared those public variables as friend and I had to redeclare those same ones as public so my other code could run. What am I doing wrong? Would you like to see my code? (I didn't put it up because it is long)

Comment: What would help is if you could: 1) Indicate which is the parent form and which is the child form, and 2) Show us the code which creates the child form.